# Need guidance for prometheus memory utilization query

Tags: prometheus

> I am using the prometheus query **'100 - ((node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes{job="jobname"} * 100) / node_memory_MemTotal_bytes{job="jobname"})'** to get the memory utilization and it is working fine.
>
> The above query is giving the result for current memory utilization.
>
> I need to reconstruct the query to get the memory utilization for last 1 hour.For example, if the memory utilization reaches more than 10 MB at 9.15 am and the current memory utilization is 2 MB at 10 am, now i need to check whether the memory utilization is more than 9 MB between 9 am to 10 am
>
> kindly guide me how to construct the prometheus query for it, i think it is something like,
>   **'(100 - ((node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes{job="jobname"} * 100) / node_memory_MemTotal_bytes{job="jobname"}))>9[1H]'**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you need [SLI value](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/availability-part-deux-CRE-life-lessons) answering the question: how much time the `jobname` used more than 90% of memory over the last hour? Then the following PromQL query should answer the question:

```
avg_over_time(
    ((1 - node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes{job="jobname"} /
    node_memory_MemTotal_bytes{job="jobname"}) >bool 0.9)[1h:1m]
)
```

The returned value will be in the range `[0..1]`, where `0` means 0% (i.e. memory usage didn't exceed 90% during the last hour), while `1` means 100% (i.e. memory usage was higher than 90% all the time during the last hour).

The query uses the following PromQL features:

- [subquery](https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/)
- [bool modifier for comparison operator](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#comparison-binary-operators)
- [avg_over_time](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#aggregation_over_time) function.

Comment: Love the answer with links to documentation - thanks @valyala!

Answer (score 0):

> 100 - ((node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes{job="jobname"} * 100) / node_memory_MemTotal_bytes{job="jobname"})[30m:1m]
>
> This will list the memory utilization values for every 1 minute